# Filter textual data and count records corresponding to a specific value

Tags: perl, data-structures, perl-data-structures

From the data below I would like to find out how many unique "Over quota"  lines there are corresponding to the ID values that start each line (*e.g.* `38148141CEB*`),  Each ID should only be counted once, even though there are multiple "Over quota" lines. What sort of data structure would be best to use for this task? How can I transform the data to achieve this?

## Sample Input

```
38148141CEB*   55166 Tue May 19 20:38:45  aaa@bbb.com
                                     aaa@nwegweg.com

AABFF141D0F*    6289 Tue May 19 20:38:44  MAILER-DAEMON
                                     rgerg@rgerger.com

3F384141CAF*   15422 Tue May 19 20:38:44  MAILER-DAEMON
                                     gregrg@gserhweh.com

6E5F1142129    59842 Tue May 19 17:22:39  rhgregr@grehedh.in
(connect to mail.rtherh.com.hk[118.142.113.41]:25: Connection timed out)
                                     hbed@herer.com.hk

64ACF141E4D     7026 Tue May 19 14:21:14  hdtjndtrj@tjrftjnrf.com
(host hergherhe.herherh.com[172.16.12.160] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in      reply to end of DATA command))
                                     c@rhedhed.com
(host hergherhe.herherh.com[172.16.12.160] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     c@rhedhed.com

67E1A1420CF     2993 Tue May 19 12:36:45  erhejhe
(host z.rherh.com[172.16.12.164] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     heehedh88@drehnjedthnj.com
(host hergherhe.herherh.com[172.16.12.160] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     c@rhedhed.com

680911418C9    11041 Tue May 19 13:59:49  efswegrwe
(host zgewsegws.nrhsrhedr.com[172.16.12.161] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     wrhwrg@etheherg.com

666611416DD    29459 Tue May 19 11:35:58  erherhe@ejerthjrth.com
(host herer.herwsrh.com[172.16.12.152] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     rggerhed@erhjehjedtr.com
(host hergherhe.herherh.com[172.16.12.160] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     c@rhedhed.com
(host hergherhe.herherh.com[172.16.12.160] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     c@rhedhed.com

643F9142006    11077 Tue May 19 11:34:32  tejeastj@eherjhe.com
(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=tjedtjedt.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
                                     tedjedth@edtjedthghr.com

62980141A8C   464040 Tue May 19 15:52:06  etjertj@jrtjedtj.com.hk
(host zherherh.com[172.16.12.159] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     trjerjer@rherherh.com

6DD47142017    20049 Tue May 19 11:04:34  erhedrhje
(host ejedtjedrth.com[172.16.12.161] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     ehjdthjdr@etjtdfteh.com

696AD1420A4     7679 Tue May 19 15:09:05  wrgwsrg
(host rwherhe.hre.com[172.16.12.157] said: 452 4.2.2 Over quota (in reply to end of DATA command))
                                     wegw@gwrhbwrg.com
```

## Sample output

The output I need would look something like this:

```
7 Over quota:
64ACF141E4D, 67E1A1420CF, 680911418C9, 666611416DD, 62980141A8C, 6DD47142017, 696AD1420A4
```

Comment: Have you attempted a solution to this problem? Please show it if you have.

Comment: Hi. Stack Overflow is a site for helping people with programming problems. It's not a coding service. Those exist, but usually they cost money. If  you would like some assistance with your coding problem, I'd suggest taking a look at [ask] and redrafting your question accordingly.

Comment: You didn't *even* share what the value of this **"quota"** is.

Comment: Oops ... I'm a bit of a `push @over` I guess :-P   @mak-on-in ... If you want to continue to be part of Stackoverflow you should try to improve your question; more clearly formulate your requirements; have a clear and relevant title/subject that connects your problem to some general programming question/technique; and at least make an *attempt* to solve it (in this case with perl).

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your data into an array of arrays and then iterate through the array elements to check for the "Over quota" statement.

This one-liner will `split` the input on blank lines (`split/\n{2,}/`) and uses `push` to put the resulting records in an array (`@quotalog`) of anonymous arrays (note the anonymous array constructors `[ ]`):

```
 perl -n0E 'push @quotalog, map { s/\s+/ /gr ; [split] } split/\n{2,}/ ;
            for (@quotalog){ say $_->[0] if ("@$_" =~ /Over/) }' quotadata.txt
```

**Output**:

```
64ACF141E4D
67E1A1420CF
680911418C9
666611416DD
62980141A8C
6DD47142017
696AD1420A4
```

Or, to approximate your sample output:

```
perl -n0E 'push @quotalog, map { [split] } split/\n{2,}/ ; 
   for (@quotalog){ push @over, $_->[0] if ("@$_" =~ /Over/) }
   print ~~@over, " Over quota:\n" ; print join ", ", @over,"\n";' quotadata.txt
```

**Output**:

```
7 Over quota: 
64ACF141E4D, 67E1A1420CF, 680911418C9, 666611416DD, 62980141A8C, 6DD47142017, 696AD1420A4,
```

You might instead want to transform the data into a hash of arrays. Here we use a "**double `map` to a hash**" to create the hash and `Data::Dumper` to view it (as an alternative you could use [`Data::Printer`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer)):

```
 perl -MData::Dumper -n0E 'map { $quotas{$_->[0]} = [ @{ $_ }[1...$#$_] ] } 
         map { [ split ] } split/\n{2,}/ ; print Dumper \%quotas' quotadata.txt
```

This is just for illustrative purposes - the second `map` (*i.e.* the first `map` the list of `split` records sees) might be better using a regex instead of a simple `split`.  In any case, once your data is nicely arranged your can begin to extract information from it - though for that a longer script form application would be more appropriate.

Have a terminal or browser window open on [The Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) (*cf.* `perdoc perldsc`) as you experiment and you'll learn quite a bit with your relatively simple exercise.